# How to delete contacts of a particular group programmatically in ios 5?

Tags: ios

I am new to ios. I want to delete contacts of a particular group programmatically in ios. Please provide me a solution for this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show any research effort

Answer (score 1):

```
CFErrorRef error;
ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreate();

NSArray *groups = (NSArray *) ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups(ab);

for (id _group in groups)
{
    NSString *currentGroupName = [[NSString alloc] init];
    currentGroupName = (NSString*) ABRecordCopyValue(_group, kABGroupNameProperty);

    if ([groupName isEqualToString:currentGroupName])
    {
        ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(ab, _group, &error);

    }
}
ABAddressBookSave(ab, nil);
```

Hope this helps.. :)